# How to separate variables and create new sheet in VBA excel?

Tags: vba, excel

So far I have this code. It does what it needs to, but I need it to do one extra step. Right now, It separates the names in the `F column` and creates a new worksheet for each name. However I need some names to be in the same worksheet. For Example, right now if `A,B,C,D` are all mixed in `Column F` in `worksheet 1` , the current code creates 4 new `worksheets`, one have `A`, next having `B`, etc. But I need, for example `A` and `B` to be in the same worksheet. How can this be done?

```
Sub company_statement()
    Dim lr As Long
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim vcol, i As Integer
    Dim icol As Long
    Dim myarr As Variant
    Dim title As String
    Dim titlerow As Integer 

    vcol = 6
    Set ws = Sheets("Company Statement Hanley")
    lr = ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, vcol).End(xlUp).Row
    title = "A1:AE1"
    titlerow = ws.Range(title).Cells(1).Row
    icol = ws.Columns.Count
    ws.Cells(1, icol) = "Unique" 

    For i = 2 To lr
        On Error Resume Next
        If ws.Cells(i, vcol) <> "" And _
            Application.WorksheetFunction.Match(ws.Cells(i, vcol), ws.Columns(icol), 0) = 0 Then 

            ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, icol).End(xlUp).Offset(1) = ws.Cells(i, vcol)
        End If
    Next 

    myarr = Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose(ws.Columns(icol).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants)) 

    ws.Columns(icol).Clear 

    For i = 2 To UBound(myarr)
        ws.Range(title).AutoFilter field:=vcol, Criteria1:=myarr(i) & ""
        If Not Evaluate("=ISREF('" & myarr(i) & "'!A1)") Then 

            Sheets.Add(after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)).Name = myarr(i) & ""
        Else
            Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Move after:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
        End If 

        ws.Range("A" & titlerow & ":A" & lr).EntireRow.Copy Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Range("A1") 

        Sheets(myarr(i) & "").Columns.AutoFit
    Next 

    ws.AutoFilterMode = False
    ws.Activate
End Sub
```

Comment: `On Error Resume Next` ==> usually a bad idea, especially when used without checking `Err.Number` and turning error handling back on.

Comment: Next time you post code, please format it so it's human-readable because right now it's almost only machine-readable.

Comment: *Please*, indent your code and use one [indenting style](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style) consistently throughout your code. Doing so makes it **much** easier to read/maintain. Doing so for code you place on Stack Overflow makes it much more likely both that users will up-vote your posts and that people will put time into Answering your Questions. It doesn't really matter which style your choose (although, for some languages, some styles are more appropriate than others). But, *pick one* and *use it consistently* for all code in a single project.

Comment: Maybe it's just late but at least half of that code makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Purposefully used a lot of different techniques for you to work with / learn. Goodluck, hope it helps

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim wbMain                      As Workbook
    Dim wsMain                      As Worksheet
    Dim rngMain                     As Range
    Dim RngCategoryOne              As Range
    Dim RngCategoryTwo              As Range
    Dim RngCategoryThree            As Range
    Dim rng                         As Range
    Dim SheetNames                  As Variant
    Dim str                         As Variant

    Set wbMain = ThisWorkBook 
    Set wsMain = wbMain.Sheets("MAIN")
    Set rngMain = wsMain.Range("A1:A10")

    For Each rng In rngMain
        Select Case rng
        Case "A", "B"
            If RngCategoryOne Is Nothing Then
                Set RngCategoryOne = rng
            Else
                Set RngCategoryOne = Union(rng, RngCategoryOne)
            End If
        Case "C"
            If RngCategoryTwo Is Nothing Then
                Set RngCategoryTwo = rng
            Else
                Set RngCategoryTwo = Union(rng, RngCategoryTwo)
            End If
        Case "D"
                If RngCategoryThree Is Nothing Then
                Set RngCategoryThree = rng
            Else
                Set RngCategoryThree = Union(rng, RngCategoryThree)
            End If
        End Select
    Next rng

    SheetNames = Array("CATEGORY ONE", "CATEGORY TWO", "CATEGORY THREE")

    For Each str In SheetNames
        Call AddNewWorksheet(wbMain, str)
    Next str

    wbMain.Sheets("CATEGORY ONE").Range("A1:A" & RngCategoryOne.Count) = RngCategoryOne.Value
    wbMain.Sheets("CATEGORY TWO").Range("A1:A" & RngCategoryTwo.Count) = RngCategoryTwo.Value
    wbMain.Sheets("CATEGORY THREE").Range("A1:A" & RngCategoryThree.Count) = RngCategoryThree.Value

    wsMain.Activate
    wsMain.Range("A1").Select
End Sub

Sub AddNewWorksheet(ByRef wb As Workbook, ByVal wsName As Variant)
    With wb.Sheets
        .Add(after:=wb.Sheets(.Count)).name = wsName
    End With
End Sub
```